# Странная ссылка полного поста - ?p=375

Tags: wordpress

По какой-то причине (я начал редактировать страницы и изменять на них контент) стали непонятные ссылки на полный пост [https://сайт.ру/?p=372](https://xn--80aswg.xn--p1ag/?p=372) . Я уже все перепробовал, ничего не помогает, ребят прошу - помогите...

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Обычное такие ссылки получают неопубликованные посты в режиме просмотра. Если это опубликованные посты, то проверьте, какой именно url Вы дали посту при создании (по умолчанию его надо прописывать ручками самостоятельно, иначе могут быть любые сюрпризы), а также какой формат ссылок у Вас указан в настройках wp

Comment: Исправьте в админке Настройки -> Постоянные Ссылки. Похоже, что у вас выбран вариант "Простые". Установите "Название записи".

Comment: Исправь вопрос, внятно  описав где "стали", что делал, как надо и пр.

Comment: @SeVlad в настройках постоянных ссылок вордпресс стоит Название записи. Раньше этих ссылок не было, но когда я начал изменять контент на сайте появились эти ссылки... не знаю вообще что делать - может нужно как-то где-то что-то прописать !?

Comment: @Gyn, не нужно мне лично в комментах что-то объяснять. Исправь вопрос.